# Manhwa where the female lead is killed by her sister (or cousin) but is reincarnated after the male lead uses a giant magic stone to turn back time

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I remember really liking the story but can't remember the name. Basically the female lead is killed by her sister, whom the female lead thinks is pregnant with the male lead's child. But it turns out that the male lead was in love with the female lead, so he uses a giant magic stone to turn back time. I don't know if this detail will help, but the giant magic stone was red.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is ***[Revolutionary Princess Eve](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/cq7jfal/revolutionary-princess-eve)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Princess Evienrose, despite advocating fiercely for the rights of the homunculi rebels, now awaits death at their hands… that is until she is poisoned by her own sister! Awakening eight years in the past, Eve now has one goal: become the Empress and liberate the homunculi to stop the rebellion from ever happening! To do this, she appoints the rebel king himself, Mikaelis Agnito, as her personal knight. But with Eve’s scheming sisters standing in the way, the fight for the crown is on, and the fate of the Hadelamid empire rests in her hands!

The protagonist is Eve, the seventh princess of Hadelamid Empire. The royal family were recently overthrown by a rebellion, and most of them were executed, with the exception of Eve and her younger sister, Rosenitte.

Eve has spent the last month in confinement, and believes that the rebel leader, Mikael, plans to keep either her or her sister alive, as the 'Philosopher's Stone' -- a large, red magic stone --only responds to imperial blood. She reasons that since Rosenitte is already in love with Mikael, he'll keep her alive, and have Eve executed in the near future.

Eve is subsequently visited by Rosenitte, who reveals that she's pregnant and names Mikael as the father. Rosenitte also claims that Eve is due to be executed today in a slow and painful manner, and convinces her to commit suicide by drinking poison in order to avoid that.

It turns out that Rosenitte wanted Eve out of the way because she knew Mikael was in love with her, and calculated that with Eve gone, he'd be all hers. When Mikael learns of Eve's death though, he uses the Philosopher's Stone to turn back time in order to give her another chance at life.

[image] [image]

Comment: If so, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263127/princess-in-evil-family-poisoned-by-sister-knight-who-can-turn-back-time/263129#263129