# Isekai where the main character is poisoned by her sister and is sent back in time without knowing that the male lead loves her

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, isekai

I remember the main character was at one point talking to her sister who was going to marry the male lead but the sister convinced her that the male lead hates her and wants to kill her.

So the sister gave the main character poison to drink. She drinks it, no surprise there and dies, but then travels back in time not knowing that the male lead actually loves her.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! I've edited in that detail, but please do [edit] in any more helpful details. There's a list if you look at [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). When you can, please take the [tour] and learn about how [ask], as well as how accepting answers works here. Thanks again! Share and enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly *[Revolutionary Princess Eve](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/revolutionary-princess-eve)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/263129/102326). It is licensed by [Tapas](https://tapas.io/series/revolutionary-princess-eve/info).

[image: Front cover of Revolutionary Princess Eve]

> Princess Evienrose, despite advocating fiercely for the rights of the homunculi rebels, now awaits death at their hands… that is until she is poisoned by her own sister! Awakening eight years in the past, Eve now has one goal: become the Empress and liberate the homunculi to stop the rebellion from ever happening! To do this, she appoints the rebel king himself, Mikaelis Agnito, as her personal knight. But with Eve’s scheming sisters standing in the way, the fight for the crown is on, and the fate of the Hadelamid empire rests in her hands!

The poisoning happens in chapter 2; the main character's sister tells her that, as part of the aftermath of the revolution in the synopsis, she will be brutally killed by the leader, because he hates her. She gives her some poison so it will at least be a painless death. It is then shown that the sister just wanted to get rid of the woman the leader loved and take him for herself.

[image: Sister gives her poison]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @user158865 You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).