# Help me find this manhwa about a girl poisoned by her sister

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I’m trying to find a manhwa.  I can’t remember everything clearly but I remember that the main character is able to use magic and was in a room with some guy and a girl that I think is her sister. The main character is blond maybe even white/grey haired.  Her sister poisons her.  She then later wakes up like normal (revived?) I can't remember what else there is but I’ve been trying to find this manhwa for some time now.

Edit: I just remembered the title might have “time” in it.  I'm not too sure but it might be correct.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: i think i read it maybe last year

Comment: You mention hourglass; The villainess reverses the hourglass? (or "turns" the hourglass). In this, she is killed by a public execution, not poisoning, but it could be mixed up memories. Another option, just from "blonde female lead, sister poisons" is  Revolutionary Princess Eve. Which was just posted as an answer as I type this.

Comment: Since you've accepted the answer, I have marked this question as a duplicate to one that has been answered before. You will still get points for this question when it is upvoted. And, as you can see if you click through, we've had this one a few times before. :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "later wakes up" you mean she wakes up *earlier*, years in the past, it may be *[Revolutionary Princess Eve](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/revolutionary-princess-eve)*:

> Princess Evienrose, despite advocating fiercely for the rights of the homunculi rebels, now awaits death at their hands… that is until she is poisoned by her own sister! Awakening eight years in the past, Eve now has one goal: become the Empress and liberate the homunculi to stop the rebellion from ever happening! To do this, she appoints the rebel king himself, Mikaelis Agnito, as her personal knight. But with Eve’s scheming sisters standing in the way, the fight for the crown is on, and the fate of the Hadelamid empire rests in her hands!

The female lead is blonde:

[image: Front cover of Revolutionary Princess Eve]

As a member of the imperial family, her blood can be used to activate the Philosopher's Stone and do magic.

It's [published on Tapas](https://m.tapas.io/series/revolutionary-princess-eve/info), where some of the episodes are free to read.

See also [Princess in evil family poisoned by sister, knight who can turn back time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/263127/82909)