# Manhwa in which the male lead sends the main character back in time?

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga

I'm looking for a manhwa where the male lead sends the main character girl back in time and we find out about it in later episodes. I guess the main male character was the main character girl's bodyguard or servant and he had brown hair.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from my answer to [Princess in evil family poisoned by sister, knight who can turn back time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263127/princess-in-evil-family-poisoned-by-sister-knight-who-can-turn-back-time/263129#263129)

*[Revolutionary Princess Eve](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/revolutionary-princess-eve)*

[image: Front cover of Revolutionary Princess Eve]

> Princess Evienrose, despite advocating fiercely for the rights of the homunculi rebels, now awaits death at their hands… that is until she is poisoned by her own sister! Awakening eight years in the past, Eve now has one goal: become the Empress and liberate the homunculi to stop the rebellion from ever happening! To do this, she appoints the rebel king himself, Mikaelis Agnito, as her personal knight. But with Eve’s scheming sisters standing in the way, the fight for the crown is on, and the fate of the Hadelamid empire rests in her hands!

Mikaelis rewinds time in [Episode 3](https://m.tapas.io/episode/2242112).

Found with a search for `manhua princess poisoned knight "time travel"`