Manhwa where the male lead makes a wish for the female lead to return to life
The female lead (FL) was incited by a woman — as far as I remember, she was a relative, either of the FL or the male lead (ML) — to sacrifice herself to a magic stone first, instead of waiting for orders from the ML (so the FL would indeed be a sacrifice). Not long after, the ML found out and rushed to the offering place, even though it was too late; the FL already died. The ML was sad and finally asked a request to the magic stone, so that the FL would be revived. The FL came back to life.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Is this Revolutionary Princess Eve...?

Princess Evienrose, despite advocating fiercely for the rights of the homunculi rebels, now awaits death at their hands… that is until she is poisoned by her own sister! Awakening eight years in the past, Eve now has one goal: become the Empress and liberate the homunculi to stop the rebellion from ever happening! To do this, she appoints the rebel king himself, Mikaelis Agnito, as her personal knight. But with Eve’s scheming sisters standing in the way, the fight for the crown is on, and the fate of the Hadelamid empire rests in her hands!

The protagonist, Eve, is the seventh princess of Hadelamid Empire. The royal family were recently overthrown by a rebellion and most of them were executed, with the exception of Eve and her younger sister, Rosenitte.
Eve has spent the last month in confinement and believes that the rebel leader, Mikael, plans to keep either her or her sister alive, as the Philosopher's Stone -- a magic stone belonging to the royal family -- only responds to imperial blood. She reasons that since Rosenitte is already in love with Mikael, he'll keep her alive and have Eve executed in the near future. However, Mikael is secretly in love with Eve.
Eve is subsequently visited by Rosenitte, who claims that Eve is due to be executed today in a slow and painful manner, and convinces her to commit suicide by drinking poison in order to avoid that.



It turns out that Rosenitte wanted Eve out of the way because she knew Mikael was in love with her and calculated that with Eve gone, he'd be all hers. When Mikael finds Eve dead, he is devastated and orders a sage to use the Philosopher's Stone turn back time to give her a chance to change her fate.



You can read the full manhwa at Tapas.

If so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/263127/princess-in-evil-family-poisoned-by-sister-knight-who-can-turn-back-time/263129#263129
